# Как убрать дублирование контента главной страницы WP?

Tags: php, wordpress, cms

При подключении WordPress к `html` вёрстке, на всех страницах под блоками дублируется контент с главной страницы. Вот ссылка: [bb-talkin](http://bb-talkin.ru/).

Подскажите пожалуйста, как убрать дублирование?

Comment: Натянуть вёрстку на тему WP. Которую нужно будет создать самому

Comment: А как вы подключаете? Покажите код? Мне кажется вы два раза подключили `headrer.php` или в `index.php` подключили что-то два раза.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оставил контент главной странице в файле page.php, и в связи с этим информация начала дублироваться по другим страницам. Если кому интересно, на будущее - при добавление кода, не забудьте раскидать код по страницам, а в page.php оставить только:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как натянуть вёрстку на WP можно посмотреть тут > https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC
Либо же обратитесь к специалистам.